# Question mark in MYSQL console screen means?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MYSQL 5.6.17. For the status column, given in the image, I use BIT datatype and values I use are 1 and 0. These values are displayed accurately in the GUI but on the console screen, they are displayed as question mark. Why is this so? Is there any problem?[image]

Comment: What you're seeing is unicode null character since you're using a bit field, and the value of those are zeroes. It's displayed as a question mark inside a square. When a value is applied to unicode table, that's the character you get back. There are no problems involved whatsoever. Know your environment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: Means there is no need to worry about it? @N.B

Comment: Yes, no need to worry about it. @N.B. You actually should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment - there's no problem involved, everything is fine :)

What you're seeing is unicode representation for the null character (all zeroes). Since you are dealing with a bit field, and its value is apparently zero, that's how it gets rendered in the terminal when unicode table is applied to that value.